# Changing a for loop to a while loop doesn't work correctly (simple code)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I want this output:

```
Insert a integer: 13
13
14
16
17
19
```

Using a `for` loop, it works fine:

```
for( ; ; num++)
{
    if (num%3==0)
        continue;
    else
        if(num%10==0)
            break;

    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

But when I try change to a `while` loop:

```
while(1)
{
    if (num%3==0)
        continue;
    else
        if(num%10==0)
            break;

    printf("%d\n", num);
    num++;
}
```

Something strange happens:

```
Insert a integer: 13
13
14
```

Can you guys help me, please?

Comment: In your `while` loop `num` doesn't get incremented on loop iterations where `num % 3 == 0` is true.  The `continue` will *not* jump down to the last statement in your `while` block. The `for` loop version *always* increments `num` on every iteration since that's how the 3rd expression in a `for` loop is handled.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `num++` when changing `for` to `while` loop:

```
while(1)
{
    if (num%3==0) {
        num++; /* <- add this */

        continue;
    }
    else
        if(num%10==0)
            break;

    printf("%d\n", num);
    num++;
}
```

*two increments* `num++` in *one* loop look ugly, so you'll probably want to *redesign* the loop into

```
while (num % 10 != 0) {
  if (num % 3 != 0) 
    printf("%d\n", num);

  num++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the `num++` line at the start of your code (while loop).
As when the loop reaches `num%3==0`, it keeps on re-iterating.

```
num--;

while(1)
{
    num++;
    if (num%3==0)
        continue;
    else
        if(num%10==0)
            break;

    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

Comment: If num is incremented initially,the input number will be skipped. Ricardo wants that also to be pro cessed.

Comment: you can always start from num-1

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
Do
{    
    if (num%3==0)
        continue;
    else
        if(num%10==0)
            break;

    printf("%d\n", num);
   }while(num++);
```

Comment: Thank you, Twinkle.

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I need the first number is the number inserted.

Comment: The change from `++num` to `num++` doesn't really affect anything.  You could convert to a `do { … } while (num++);` loop, of course.